# Bootstrap 4 - col with col-sm-12 is not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Am using bootstrap 4 and have my 4 columns in 1 row. When I go to mobile I want the 4 columns to become 1 column (essentially add a row per column.)

My understanding was that if I add col-sm-12 to my divs this would do what I want but it is not working. What am I missing?

```
<div class="col col-sm-12">
<div>Required Forms</div>
<p>View what forms are required for shipping to the event.</p>
</div>
<!-- col -->

<div class="col col-sm-12">
<div>Invoice Instructions</div>
<p>Instructions on how to complete the commercial invoice form.</p>
</div>
<!-- col -->

<div class="col col-sm-12">
<div>Labeling &amp; Packing</div>
<p>Tips on packing and labeling your shipment.</p>
</div>
<!-- col -->

<div class="col col-sm-12">
<div>Wood Packing</div>
<p>Important information on wood packings (includes skids / pallets)</p>
</div>
<!-- col -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For mobile devices like smartphones, you should use the smalles breakpoint class, which is just `col-*`, the `col-sm-*` classes are for slightly larger screens (like landscape view of phones).

You can check the responsive breakpoint limits in [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

**NOTE:** Also keep in mind that the `col-*` classes will apply to the specified breakpoint onwards, so if you just use `col-12`, then the element will use the full with on all screens, if you want this to change you have to set another class for larger devices like `col-md-4` so the element only uses 4 columns on tablet screens.

```css
.col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div>Required Forms</div>
    <p>View what forms are required for shipping to the event.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- col -->

  <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div>Invoice Instructions</div>
    <p>Instructions on how to complete the commercial invoice form.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- col -->

  <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div>Labeling &amp; Packing</div>
    <p>Tips on packing and labeling your shipment.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- col -->

  <div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div>Wood Packing</div>
    <p>Important information on wood packings (includes skids / pallets)</p>
  </div>
  <!-- col -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Just test working well:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
Content Center
</div>
</div>
```